# Face recognition via facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Currently, if I have a facebook friend whom I've tagged in a picture that I've uploaded, when I upload a picture with his face on it, facebook automatically suggests his user as a tag.

Is it possible to emulate this same behavior via the facebook graph api or the SDK?

In other words, if I use the api as described on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/ to upload a photo (described under "Creating") of a user that my account is friends with, is there any way facebook will make that same suggestion in the request return parameters or something like that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. You can use [Facematch](https://github.com/louisondumont/facematch), an unofficial wrapper for the Facebook face recognition feature.

> When you upload a picture on Facebook, the /photos/tagging/recognition endpoint is called. This program uploads a private picture (using Facebook API) + calls the recognition endpoint (by simulating a browser using the user's information).

Comment: Note that currently tag suggestions are only available in the US: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=838680732811167 and that there are privacy settings to restrict who can see your name in the tag suggestions: https://www.facebook.com/help/463455293673370/ which most people are likely to leave on friends only.

Comment: For future viewers, Facematch and fbrecog won't work now, as the facebook API has removed the scope `publish_actions` from its SDK, on which these apps worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/samj1912/fbrecog. Python wrapper for Facebook face recognition. And the only one in my knowledge that currently works.

Comment: Does it recognize your friends?

Answer (score 0):

Face recognition is not exposed via the Graph API, so no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook DeepFace face recognition model is wrapped by the deepface package for python. Also, the package offers an API to be called as rest services as well.

```
!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
resp = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = "DeepFace")
print(resp)
```